# How to combine multiple criteria into an Elasticsearch NEST query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to NEST. I have failed to understand how I can combine multiple criterion into a NEST query despite my searching over various forums.

My C# code is here:

```
var mediaIds = "my-vid-123|my-vid-456"; // This is in fact passed from UI.
var stationId = "1"; // Also passed from UI.


QueryContainer query = new QueryContainer();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaIds))
{
    var lstMediaIds = mediaIds.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    QueryContainer qr = new QueryContainer();
    lstMediaIds.ForEach(vi => {
        qr &= new TermQuery { Field = "VideoID", Value = vi};
    });

    query &= qr;
}

if (stationId != "" & stationId != "0")
{
    query &= new TermQuery
    {
        Field = "StationID",
        Value = stationId
    };
}

var result = _db.Search<MediaSummary>(s => s
                .Index("mediasummary-*")
                .Type(typeof(MediaSummary))
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .Query(q => query)
                );

var count = result.Total; //Always comes 0
var mediaSumm = result.Documents.ToList();  //Empty list
```

The `count` always comes zero and `mediaSumm` list is empty, although the records show up from **Kibana**.
Where am I doing wrong? Please guide.

Comment: What does the query sent by NEST look like? Take a look at the troubleshooting section on capturing the request: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html

Comment: You got no error in result response? please check. Also please test without  .Skip(skip) .Take(take), in fact just test with a little querry to start. Also please replcae != "" by !string.IsnullOrEmpty(stationId ) && (and not &)